# 4g dongle internet connection problem?

Tags: networking, usb, connection, internet

I am having problem with establishing internet connection on my RPi(Raspbian) with Huawei USB dongle. I went through many tutorials that I found on internet but I still can't connect on internet via RPi. I would be very happy if someone can help me, I lost few days with that so far, first I thought it would be very simple task...

These are my steps so far:

- I installed mode-switch, so my device switches to modem: 12d1:14db, these I can check with lsusb.
  [image]
- with config-a I can check that I got new interface eth1. 
  [image]
- I can go to 192.168.8.1 modem web-page, where I can see that my conenction is working (I can check for updates for example, see status of connection, etc., ..). **Because of that, I don't know if I still need sakis3g script for example?** I also tried with sakis3g, but always got "Failed to connect".
- Then I added route "sudo route add default gw 192.168.8.1". I can check that with netstat -nr (please, see first picture).
- If I plug out my LAN cable, my internet is not working anymore. I got error "no route to host". I also cant ping www.google.com or 8.8.8.8.

I don't know what is wrong. As I understand, I have working internet connection on 192.168.8.1, I just need to route traffic via that address. Am I right? I also tried something with enabling IP packet forwarding in sysctl file, but nothing was working.

I anybody has answer or solution for my problem, please let me know. I just want to have working internet connection via USB dongle 4g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in automatic selection of network. Then I changed it to 3G and it works. It's weird, but it's working. :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an issue, but please try connecting the USB 4G dongle through a **powered** USB hub.  In my experience with cellular dongles, they tend to draw a lot of current and in large pulses, possibly more than the Pi is able to provide.  Voltage drops could then result in connection issues.